# Conditional expectations, $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and assume that $E[X|Y]=Y$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=X$.

I want to show that $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=1$.

I started working on 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)\mathbb{1}_{\{X>z,Y\leq z\}}] + \mathbb{E}[(X-Y)\mathbb{1}_{\{X\leq z,Y\leq z\}}]
\end{align}
for arbitrary $z \in \mathbb{R}$. However, I do not know how to continue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $h:\Bbb R\to(0,1)$ be continuous and strictly increasing. Show that $\Bbb E[(X-Y)\cdot(h(X)-h(Y))]=0$. Notice that $(X-Y)\cdot(h(X)-h(Y))\ge 0$ with equality only if $X=Y$.